# Create a Database with ADOdb Active Record for PHP

Tags: php, adodb-php

I'm trying to use ADOdb for PHP for the first time and I'm having trouble trying to find out how to create a new database.

This is the code I have so far.

```
include_once('adodb/adodb.inc.php');
include_once('adodb/adodb-active-record.inc.php');
include_once('adodb/adodb-exceptions.inc.php');
$db = NewADOConnection('mysql://'.$username.':'.$password.'@localhost/'.$newdb);
ADOdb_Active_Record::SetDatabaseAdapter($db);
```

The error I get:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ADODB_Exception' with message 'mysql error: [1049: Unknown database 'test'] in CONNECT(localhost, 'root', '****', test)'
```

I know the database doesn't exist, I want to know how to create it via code.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an empty holding database and connect to it. then, if you're user has the permissions, run a create script.

As a reminder, being able to execute dba scripts over the Web has inherent security issues. Please be careful.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks. This is for a back-office installation only. As soon it's done the script with the database creation is deleted.